# Node.JS Error: Cannot find module 'posix' (using Cygwin)

Tags: module, node.js, cygwin, posix

I am attempting to run [a simple node.js webserver](https://gist.github.com/246761) using Cygwin. I copied [the file](https://gist.github.com/raw/246761/2b6edb443e541b0e40fab8b54496954f97e7e6b2/index.js) into `test.js` after [installing node](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) and this is what I got.

```
$ node test.js

node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'posix'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:299:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:245:25)
    at require (module.js:327:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/test.js:27:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:383:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:389:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:315:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:276:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:402:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)

user@host ~
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of node did you install? If you take a look at the [node change log](https://github.com/joyent/node/raw/master/ChangeLog), `require('posix')` was moved into `require('fs')` in the API back in version 0.1.29 (2010.02.17). The gist is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code to the newest node.js build here: https://gist.github.com/862132 still I recommend finding other more recent example since this code is not that great (specially after I updated it).

Comment: I think that it any webserver under 100 lines of code will be an excellent starting place. If you take out the comments and remove a few blank lines, this example fits perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the gist by mistake, I will uploaded it again later.